# Unable to create or update an Asset\Image when saving a Pimcore object

Tags: pimcore

My goal is to create / update objects by using a csv file. csv file is fine and allready heavy used.
I wrote a complete script for that, most setSomething() works very well with text, structured Datas etc.. but i'm facing a trouble with the Images. I read the doc twice...

https://pimcore.com/docs/4.6.x/Development_Documentation/Objects/Object_Classes/Data_Types/Image_Types.html

```
$image = Asset\Image::getByPath("/examples/example1.jpg");
$object->setImage($image);
$object->save();
```

and that exactly what's i did to create / update $article

```
$marque = Pimcore\Model\Asset\Image::getByPath("/Catalog/Marques/".$image);
$article->setEarg($marque);
$article->save();
```

please note that :

- $image exists,
- $marque is found, and is an instance of Asset\Image
- setEarg($marque) is properly defined to set an Image data field
- in UI all works fine
- cache cleared

Is it possible i misunderstood something ? 
I also searched in passed Issues, no luck.
https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues

Maybe someone did face the same problem ? Anc could a hint on how to solve that ?

Regards,

Comment: Is there any information in the logs? website/var/log/debug.log

Comment: no @PiotrCwiecek logs are clean, only normal maintenance processus

Comment: If it seems like a cache problem, but clearing didn't fix it, maybe it's nginx/apache cache?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused...this code is working as it should.
It seems to a cache problem, even if i cleared it. In the UI image did appear after some minutes / hour. Now it appear immedialtly. This question can be closed, but this push me to another one... how did this cache / deffer problem happened. If i find something i will update here.